# Convert RepeatedField<ByteString> to Byte[]

Tags: c#, type-conversion, grpc

Defined a gRPC Python service in a Docker.

The services in my PROTO file:

```
rpc ClientCommand(ClientRequest) returns (ClientResponse){}
```

Definition of "ClientResponse":

```
message ClientResponse{
          int32  request_id             = 1;
 repeated int32  prediction_status      = 2;
 repeated string prediction_info        = 3;
 repeated string prediction_error       = 4;
 repeated string prediction_result_name = 5;
 repeated bytes  prediction_result      = 6;
 repeated bytes  prediction_config      = 7;
 repeated bytes  prediction_log         = 8;
 }
```

On client side, I want to catch the repeated bytes and convert them into a file(I know it better works with a stream but for the moment I would like to do it like this).
The repeated strings and integer I can perfectly convert to List --> OK
The repeated bytes I would like to convert to Byte[]. Their type: Google.ProtoBuf.Collections.RepeatedField<Google.ProtoBuf.ByteString>.

**At first it seems to be impossible to convert this type to a Byte[].** Could somebody help me with this please? My solution temporary:

```
byte[] test = new byte[100];
Google.Protobuf.ByteString[] test2 = new Google.Protobuf.ByteString[100];
response.PredictionResult.CopyTo(test2,0);
test2.CopyTo(test,0);
WriteFile(@"C:\programs\file.txt", test);
```

Comment: RepeatedField<Google.ProtoBuf.ByteString> is just a collection of ByteStrings. Basically you just need to iterate over all the ByteString values for write each of the ByteStrings in the file one by one (and ByteString contents can be converted to an array of bytes e.g. - writing those to a file is trivial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I figure it out:

```
public void WriteFileResult(string fileName,Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField<ByteString> data)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Count];
    ByteString[] dataByteString = new ByteString[data.Count];
    
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                if (!path.EndsWith(@"\")) path += @"\";
    
                if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, fileName)))
                    File.Delete(Path.Combine(path, fileName));
        
         using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        
                        data.CopyTo(dataByteString, 0);
                        bytes = dataByteString[0].ToByteArray();
                        
                        fs.Write(bytes, 0, (int)bytes.Length);
                        _serviceResponseModel.Json = false;
                        //fs.Close()
                    }
}
```